# Cannot assign class of type 'Mappable' to AlamoFire response

Tags: ios, swift, class, alamofire, objectmapper

So I'm doing a fetch with Alamofire, and depending on the index (see switch `currentIndex`) I want to get a different URL (works) and a Class (doesn't work).

The classes Folders and Article are both declared as follow: `class Folders : Mappable` and `class Article : Mappable`

```
    var responseMapping:Mappable?
    var URL:String = ""
    switch currentIndex {
    case 0:
        URL = "searchFolderURL".localized + searchString
        responseMapping = Folders
    case 1:
        URL = "searchArticleURL".localized + searchString
        responseMapping = Article
    default:
        print("Something went horribly wrong")
        guard URL != "" else {
            return
        }
    }
    print(URL)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseObject { (response: Response<responseMapping, NSError>) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
```

When I try the following code, it gives back the next error: `'responseMapping' is not a type` and `Cannot assign value of type 'Article.Type' to type 'Mappable?'`

What am I missing here?